# Suggestion Items not appearing after Value State Change in sap.m Table input

Tags: sapui5

I have a SuggestionItems on sap.m table input which is not appearing after value state change.

Please note that SAPUI5 Version used is **1.38.37**

I have a sap.m table with columns with Suggestion List enabled. User has to select customer number from that available suggestion list. Also he can enter manually.

Now there are list of validations depending on user input.

**XML.view**

```
<items>
    <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Input id="idCustNumber" type="Text" value="{path:'createJSON>CUSTNO'}" change="onCustValChange" liveChange="onLiveChangeCustNo"
                    startSuggestion="3" maxSuggestionWidth="400px" showSuggestion="true" suggestionItemSelected="OnSuggestionSelectedCustNumber"
                    suggest="handleSuggestCustNo" suggestionItems="{path:'ITEMVALJSON>/items', templateShareable:false}">
                           <suggestionItems>
                                        <core:Item key="{ITEMVALJSON>CustNoAndName}" text="{ITEMVALJSON>CustNoAndName}"/>
                           </suggestionItems>
                </Input>
```

**Controller.js**

```
        handleSuggestCustNo: function (oEvent) {
                var sTerm = oEvent.getParameter("suggestValue");
                oEvent.getSource().setFilterFunction(function (sTerm, oItem) {
                    // A case-insensitive 'string contains' style filter
                    return oItem.getText().match(new RegExp(sTerm, "i"));

                });
            },

            onCustValChange: function (oEvent) {
                var oInput = oEvent.getSource();
                this._validateCustValInput(oInput);
            },

            _validateCustValInput: function (oInput) {
                var oBinding = oInput.getBinding("suggestionItems");
                var value = oInput.getValue();

                if (value !== "") {
                    var filters = [new Filter("CustNo", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, value)];
                    var found = oBinding.filter(filters).getLength();

                    if (found === 0) {
                        oInput.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
                        this.sSelectedTableRow.ERRORFLAG = "X";
                        oInput.setValueStateText("Customer " + "'" + value + "' is invalid for GCC: " + "'" + this.Header.Cntry + "'");
                    } else {
                        oInput.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.None);
                        this.sSelectedTableRow.ERRORFLAG = "";
                    }
                } else {
                    oInput.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.None);
                    this.sSelectedTableRow.ERRORFLAG = "";
                }
            },
```

Now issue is, if validation is failing, I am setting the value state to error. then after value change, suggestion list is not appearing.

[Suggestion List Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PXjc.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the validation itself (or the SAPUI5 version) but in this line of code:

```
var found = oBinding.filter(filters).getLength();
```

Here you are filtering out your `suggestionItems` aggregation.... That's why they stop working: the ITEMVALJSON model is only filled with the chosen and validated value. Try to cancel a letter of the bound value in the input and you will see what I mean.

By the way I noticed two more things: you are filtering the wrong property (but maybe is only a matter of cut and paste) and your `handleSuggestCustNo` function is probably unnecessary. You can set the filter function (`setFilterFunction`) only once for your input in the initialization phase.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got that filtering on `suggestionItems` is creating problem. But then how can i do this validation. User can also enter manually instead of selecting from suggestion list.

Comment: I have to show customer no along with name on suggestion list and user can search on either of anyone. then on suggestion list select, it should bring only the customer no to the input field. Due to this old UI version, I am not able to achieve this with additional text. So I have added a extra column in the model `ITEMVALJSON>CustNoAndNam` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

My (minimal) working code,I tried it with 1.38.xx

```
                            <Table id="table" items="{ path: '/items'}">
                                <columns>
                                    <Column>
                                        <Text text="ItemNo"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column>
                                        <Text text="Name"/>
                                    </Column>
                                </columns>
                                <ColumnListItem>
                                    <cells>
                                        <Text text="{ItemNo}"/>
                                        <Input id="idCustNumber" placeholder="Suggestion test 2" type="Text" _value="{path:'localModel>CUSTNO'}" change="onCustValChange"
                                            maxSuggestionWidth="400px" showSuggestion="true" suggest="handleSuggestCustNo"
                                            suggestionItems="{path:'localModel>/items', templateShareable:true}">
                                            <suggestionItems>
                                                <core:Item text="{localModel>CustNoAndName}"/>
                                            </suggestionItems>
                                        </Input>
                                    </cells>
                                </ColumnListItem>
                            </Table>
```

Controller code:

```
onInit: function () {
    var oLocalModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
        items: [{
            CustoNo: 1,
            CustNoAndName: "Mickey Mouse"
        }, {
            CustoNo: 2,
            CustNoAndName: "Donald Duck"
        }]
    });
    this.getView().setModel(oLocalModel, "localModel");

    var oData = {
        items: [{
            ItemNo: 1
        }, {
            ItemNo: 2
        }, {
            ItemNo: 3
        }]
    };

    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);

},
handleSuggestCustNo: function (oEvent) {
    console.log("handleSuggestCustNo");
    var sTerm = oEvent.getParameter("suggestValue");
    console.log({
        sTerm
    });
},

onCustValChange: function (oEvent) {
    console.log("onCustValChange");
    var oInput = oEvent.getSource();
    this._validateCustValInput(oInput);
},

_validateCustValInput: function (oInput) {
    console.log("_validateCustValInput");
    var oBinding = oInput.getBinding("suggestionItems");
    var value = oInput.getValue();

    if (value !== "") {
        var filters = [new sap.ui.model.Filter("CustNoAndName", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, value)];
        var found = oBinding.filter(filters).getLength();

        if (found === 0) {
            oInput.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
            //this.sSelectedTableRow.ERRORFLAG = "X";
            oInput.setValueStateText("Customer " + "'" + value + "' is invalid");
        } else {
            oInput.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.None);
            //this.sSelectedTableRow.ERRORFLAG = "";
        }
    } else {
        oInput.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.None);
        //this.sSelectedTableRow.ERRORFLAG = "";
    }
    oBinding.filter([]);
}
```

The "value" property of each input is commented. Can you try this code and tell me if it works for you? Maybe I got something wrong but my `_validateCustValInput` function is always triggered.

Comment: This is working fine. But in my requirement, i have added a new field in `oLocalModel` which holds concatenation of customer and Name. I have edited my post to  add the pic.This work around i have done, because the current version is not supporting to search suggestion list on any one of this two values. But on select, it will bring customer and Customer name to their respective cells.

Comment: This is causing issue while correcting an error entry as showed in the pic.